# Registered User can't login with credentials django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

The issue i've got is my login endpoint wont permit me to login with authenticated users for unkown reasons

Here is my serializers.py file

```
class  UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id','first_name','last_name','email','is_seller','date_joined']
        extra_kwargs ={
            'password':{'write_only':True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Here is my views.py for Login

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']
        print(email)
        print(password)

        # since email is unique use first()
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
        print(user)

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(f'User {email} not found')
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(f'Incorrect Password')
        
        

        return Response(UserSerializer(user).data)
```

Now when i do try to login the and given user i get this error below from post man

```
{
    "detail": "Incorrect Password"
}
```

And these are my logs below

```
Forbidden: /api/sellers/login/
[15/Jul/2021 21:50:30] "POST /api/sellers/login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 31
```

I've been unable for hours to figure out why exactly register users can't sign in and also i am using a Custom user model and in my settings.py file the Rest_Framework is set to AllowAny...Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Were users able to authenticate at some point? Or are you building this for the first time?

Comment: You need to have `password` in your `fields` list.

Comment: @jorf.brunning I'm actually building this for the very first time...The registration endpoint works fine but for this login endpoint which has been given me problems.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68399451/registered-user-cant-login-with-credentials-django-rest-framework?noredirect=1#comment120883513_68399451) suggested, make sure your fields includes `password`. Your `extra_kwargs` for `password` still requires that `password` is either a field on the model (in the `fields` list) or defined as a type of field directly on the Serializer.

```
class  UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_seller',
            'date_joined',
            'password',  #  <- note added field
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only':True}
        }
```